# Wordpress Permalink change won't work

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I want to update my permalink structure to postfix from the "plain" type, but every time I try--I get a 404 on every page I try to visit, except for the front page. I've reset my .htaccess, deleted it and recreated it, disabled all plugins, and then tried redoing the .htaccess with the plugins still disabled--but no luck.

I do think this was caused by the "Team" plugin by pickplugins...but still no luck when deleting that and redoing the above.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure server enable Apache Mode Rewrite properly. This happen all apache servers doesn't install Mode Rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

I would begin by testing whether or not the htaccess file you are editing is being used by the Apache server. To test this, break it intentionally (writing invalid lines of codes can achieve this). Then see if you get the `500 Internal Server Error` on your page. If you get that error, then that means your htaccess file is in fact being used by the server.

if the htaccess is working then find out if `mod_rewrite` is working on your server.